# "A sickly ghostage of Chanel No.5." What does "ghostly" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

This is from  Nick Cave's novel, "The Death of Bunny Munro".
"The  couple exit the dining room leaving a sickly **ghostage** of Chanel No.5 that compounds Bunny's hangover and makes him wince and bare his teeth and return to the newspaper."
What is the meaning of "ghostage"?

Comment: In this case, it means a faint impression.

Comment: Are you asking about *ghostage*, *ghostly*, both, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Your word seems to be a made up word since I can't find a direct definition for it, however

> ghostage

appears to be a combination of "ghost" and the suffix "[-age](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-age)" with the meaning of to have characteristics of a ghost.

Perfume is invisible but can be sensed, just as ghosts may be at times.    It could be that the meaning is "haunting" or "foreboding" as with any encounter with a ghost.

Comment: A more relevant summary of [the **-age** suffix](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-age) *- productive in English with the meanings “aggregate” ( coinage; peerage; trackage), “process” ( coverage; breakage), “the outcome of” as either “the fact of” or “the physical effect or **remains of**” (**seepage; wreckage; spoilage**)*.